# Большой размер js бандла при использовании Webpack+TS+crypto-js

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack4, cryptojs

Простой код с одной лишь библиотекой [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) весит около **700кб**.
Снизить его никак не получается. Пробовал стандартный минимайзер, UglifyJS и Сlosure. Сборка с `--mode production`. Вижу, что помимо этой библиотеки, при сборке, добавляется ещё +229 hidden modules. При этом сама библиотека crypto-js не содержит [зависимостей](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/package.json#L24).

Версия Webpack 4.43.0

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/build'),
    },
    plugins: [],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {},
                    mangle: true,
                    output: null,
                    toplevel: false,
                    nameCache: null,
                    ie8: false,
                    keep_fnames: false,
                },
            }),
        ]
    },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/build",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import * as crypto from "crypto-js";

console.log(
    crypto.MD5('some_string').toString()
);
```

Вывод консоли:

```html
> my-app@1.0.0 watch /app
> webpack --mode production --watch true --display-modules


webpack is watching the files…

Hash: a167582afa929d530f49
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 7237ms
Built at: 06/24/2020 3:30:35 PM
            Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        bundle.js  706 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
bundle.js.LICENSE  110 KiB          [emitted]         
Entrypoint main [big] = bundle.js
  [0] ./node_modules/inherits/inherits_browser.js 753 bytes {0} [built]
  [1] ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 1.49 KiB {0} [built]
  [2] ./node_modules/crypto-js/core.js 22.8 KiB {0} [built]
  [3] ./node_modules/buffer/index.js 47.5 KiB {0} [built]
  [4] ./node_modules/process/browser.js 5.29 KiB {0} [built]
  [5] ./node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js 29 KiB {0} [built]
  [6] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
  [7] ./node_modules/minimalistic-assert/index.js 252 bytes {0} [built]
  [8] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/utils.js 2.34 KiB {0} [built]
  [9] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/utils.js 6.37 KiB {0} [built]
 [10] ./node_modules/elliptic/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [11] ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2.17 KiB {0} [built]
 [12] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
 [13] ./node_modules/events/events.js 13 KiB {0} [built]
 [14] ./node_modules/string_decoder/lib/string_decoder.js 9.24 KiB {0} [built]
 [15] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js 3.92 KiB {0} [built]
 [16] ./node_modules/crypto-js/evpkdf.js 3.9 KiB {0} [built]
 [17] ./node_modules/randombytes/browser.js 1.54 KiB {0} [built]
 [18] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/errors-browser.js 4.1 KiB {0} [built]
 [19] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js 4.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [20] ./node_modules/sha.js/hash.js 1.84 KiB {0} [built]
 [21] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/errors-browser.js 4.1 KiB {0} [built]
 [22] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js 4.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [23] ./node_modules/crypto-js/enc-base64.js 3.99 KiB {0} [built]
 [24] ./node_modules/crypto-js/md5.js 9.2 KiB {0} [built]
 [25] ./node_modules/create-hash/browser.js 625 bytes {0} [built]
 [26] ./node_modules/core-util-is/lib/util.js 2.95 KiB {0} [built]
 [27] ./node_modules/buffer-xor/index.js 206 bytes {0} [built]
 [28] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/common.js 2.26 KiB {0} [built]
 [29] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1.js 268 bytes {0} [built]
 [30] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/index.js 212 bytes {0} [built]
 [31] ./node_modules/process-nextick-args/index.js 1.06 KiB {0} [built]
 [32] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/aes.js 6.1 KiB {0} [built]
 [33] ./node_modules/evp_bytestokey/index.js 1.16 KiB {0} [built]
 [34] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/base.js 9.21 KiB {0} [built]
 [35] ./node_modules/parse-asn1/index.js 3.62 KiB {0} [built]
 [36] ./node_modules/crypto-js/x64-core.js 8.68 KiB {0} [built]
 [37] ./node_modules/md5.js/index.js 4.5 KiB {0} [built]
 [38] ./node_modules/util-deprecate/browser.js 1.58 KiB {0} [built]
 [39] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/end-of-stream.js 3.03 KiB {0} [built]
 [40] ./node_modules/ripemd160/index.js 4.47 KiB {0} [built]
 [41] ./node_modules/sha.js/index.js 468 bytes {0} [built]
 [42] ./node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js 351 bytes {0} [built]
 [43] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 19.8 KiB {0} [built]
 [44] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des/cipher.js 3.25 KiB {0} [built]
 [45] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/browser.js 500 bytes {0} [built]
 [46] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/index.js 364 bytes {0} [built]
 [47] ./node_modules/brorand/index.js 1.47 KiB {0} [built]
 [48] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 1.63 KiB {0} [built]
 [49] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/end-of-stream.js 3.03 KiB {0} [built]
 [50] ./node_modules/browserify-rsa/index.js 1.18 KiB {0} [built]
 [51] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic.js 371 bytes {0} [built]
 [52] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curves.js 6.28 KiB {0} [built]
 [53] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash.js 444 bytes {0} [built]
 [54] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [55] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha1.js 3.97 KiB {0} [built]
 [56] ./node_modules/crypto-js/hmac.js 3.89 KiB {0} [built]
 [57] ./node_modules/isarray/index.js 132 bytes {0} [built]
 [58] ./node_modules/hash-base/index.js 2.27 KiB {0} [built]
 [59] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js 35.1 KiB {0} [built]
 [60] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/stream-browser.js 49 bytes {0} [built]
 [61] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js 3.04 KiB {0} [built]
 [62] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/state.js 749 bytes {0} [built]
 [63] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 21.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [64] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js 7.76 KiB {0} [built]
 [65] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha256.js 3.2 KiB {0} [built]
 [66] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha512.js 7.01 KiB {0} [built]
 [67] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js 30.6 KiB {0} [built]
 [68] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/stream-browser.js 49 bytes {0} [built]
 [69] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js 1.81 KiB {0} [built]
 [70] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js 7.56 KiB {0} [built]
 [71] ./node_modules/create-hmac/browser.js 1.55 KiB {0} [built]
 [72] ./node_modules/create-hash/md5.js 111 bytes {0} [built]
 [73] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/algorithms.json 2.8 KiB {0} [built]
 [74] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/browser.js 83 bytes {0} [built]
 [75] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/precondition.js 507 bytes {0} [built]
 [76] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js 336 bytes {0} [built]
 [77] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/sync-browser.js 2.46 KiB {0} [built]
 [78] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/to-buffer.js 414 bytes {0} [built]
 [79] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des/utils.js 6.45 KiB {0} [built]
 [80] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des/des.js 3.08 KiB {0} [built]
 [81] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/ctr.js 908 bytes {0} [built]
 [82] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/incr32.js 260 bytes {0} [built]
 [83] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/list.json 3.01 KiB {0} [built]
 [84] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/authCipher.js 2.95 KiB {0} [built]
 [85] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/streamCipher.js 659 bytes {0} [built]
 [86] ./node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/generatePrime.js 2.18 KiB {0} [built]
 [87] ./node_modules/diffie-hellman/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [88] ./node_modules/miller-rabin/lib/mr.js 2.43 KiB {0} [built]
 [89] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js 35.1 KiB {0} [built]
 [90] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/stream-browser.js 49 bytes {0} [built]
 [91] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/destroy.js 3.04 KiB {0} [built]
 [92] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/state.js 749 bytes {0} [built]
 [93] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 21.3 KiB {0} [built]
 [94] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js 7.76 KiB {0} [built]
 [95] ./node_modules/minimalistic-crypto-utils/lib/utils.js 1.11 KiB {0} [built]
 [96] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/index.js 173 bytes {0} [built]
 [97] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/common.js 907 bytes {0} [built]
 [98] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/256.js 2.81 KiB {0} [built]
 [99] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/512.js 8.15 KiB {0} [built]
[100] ./node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 87.9 KiB {0} [built]
[101] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/buffer.js 3.02 KiB {0} [built]
[102] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/constants/index.js 347 bytes {0} [built]
[103] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/decoders/der.js 7.85 KiB {0} [built]
[104] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/encoders/der.js 7.82 KiB {0} [built]
[105] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/curves.json 178 bytes {0} [built]
[106] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/mgf.js 423 bytes {0} [built]
[107] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/xor.js 129 bytes {0} [built]
[108] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/withPublic.js 275 bytes {0} [built]
[109] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha256.js 5.41 KiB {0} [built]
[110] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha512.js 13.2 KiB {0} [built]
[111] ./node_modules/crypto-js/index.js 1.55 KiB {0} [built]
[112] ./src/main.ts 88 bytes {0} [built]
[113] ./node_modules/crypto-browserify/index.js 2.87 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
[114] ./node_modules/base64-js/index.js 3.85 KiB {0} [built]
[115] ./node_modules/ieee754/index.js 2.02 KiB {0} [built]
[116] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 1.63 KiB {0} [built]
[117] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js 488 bytes {0} [built]
[118] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[119] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/buffer_list.js 6.19 KiB {0} [built]
[120] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[121] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/async_iterator.js 5.82 KiB {0} [built]
[122] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/from-browser.js 101 bytes {0} [built]
[123] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_passthrough.js 1.59 KiB {0} [built]
[124] ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/pipeline.js 2.37 KiB {0} [built]
[125] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha.js 1.87 KiB {0} [built]
[126] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha1.js 1.98 KiB {0} [built]
[127] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha224.js 1.07 KiB {0} [built]
[128] ./node_modules/sha.js/sha384.js 1.14 KiB {0} [built]
[129] ./node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js 3.54 KiB {0} [built]
[130] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[131] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/BufferList.js 2.01 KiB {0} [built]
[132] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[133] ./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js 1.97 KiB {0} [built]
[134] ./node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js 6.32 KiB {0} [built]
[135] ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_passthrough.js 1.71 KiB {0} [built]
[136] ./node_modules/readable-stream/writable-browser.js 55 bytes {0} [built]
[137] ./node_modules/readable-stream/duplex-browser.js 53 bytes {0} [built]
[138] ./node_modules/readable-stream/transform.js 49 bytes {0} [built]
[139] ./node_modules/readable-stream/passthrough.js 51 bytes {0} [built]
[140] ./node_modules/create-hmac/legacy.js 969 bytes {0} [built]
[141] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/algos.js 54 bytes {0} [built]
[142] ./node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/async.js 2.58 KiB {0} [built]
[143] ./node_modules/browserify-cipher/browser.js 1.97 KiB {0} [built]
[144] ./node_modules/browserify-des/index.js 1.17 KiB {0} [built]
[145] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
[146] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des/cbc.js 1.41 KiB {0} [built]
[147] ./node_modules/des.js/lib/des/ede.js 1.3 KiB {0} [built]
[148] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/encrypter.js 2.8 KiB {0} [built]
[149] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/ecb.js 175 bytes {0} [built]
[150] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/cbc.js 342 bytes {0} [built]
[151] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/cfb.js 869 bytes {0} [built]
[152] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/cfb8.js 518 bytes {0} [built]
[153] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/cfb1.js 917 bytes {0} [built]
[154] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/modes/ofb.js 415 bytes {0} [built]
[155] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/ghash.js 1.91 KiB {0} [built]
[156] ./node_modules/browserify-aes/decrypter.js 3.14 KiB {0} [built]
[157] ./node_modules/browserify-des/modes.js 301 bytes {0} [built]
[158] ./node_modules/diffie-hellman/browser.js 1.11 KiB {0} [built]
[159] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[160] ./node_modules/miller-rabin/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
[161] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[162] crypto (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[163] ./node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/primes.json 7.06 KiB {0} [built]
[164] ./node_modules/diffie-hellman/lib/dh.js 3.79 KiB {0} [built]
[165] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/index.js 2.18 KiB {0} [built]
[166] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js 488 bytes {0} [built]
[167] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[168] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/buffer_list.js 6.19 KiB {0} [built]
[169] util (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [built]
[170] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/async_iterator.js 5.82 KiB {0} [built]
[171] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/from-browser.js 101 bytes {0} [built]
[172] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_passthrough.js 1.59 KiB {0} [built]
[173] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/pipeline.js 2.37 KiB {0} [built]
[174] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/sign.js 3.82 KiB {0} [built]
[175] ./node_modules/browserify-rsa/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
[176] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[177] ./node_modules/elliptic/package.json 2.3 KiB {0} [built]
[178] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[179] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/short.js 22.3 KiB {0} [built]
[180] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/mont.js 4.47 KiB {0} [built]
[181] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/edwards.js 10.7 KiB {0} [built]
[182] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha.js 206 bytes {0} [built]
[183] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/1.js 1.53 KiB {0} [built]
[184] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/224.js 670 bytes {0} [built]
[185] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/sha/384.js 768 bytes {0} [built]
[186] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/ripemd.js 3.47 KiB {0} [built]
[187] ./node_modules/hash.js/lib/hash/hmac.js 1.11 KiB {0} [built]
[188] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/precomputed/secp256k1.js 31.6 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
[189] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/index.js 6.08 KiB {0} [built]
[190] ./node_modules/hmac-drbg/lib/hmac-drbg.js 2.92 KiB {0} [built]
[191] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/key.js 2.96 KiB {0} [built]
[192] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/signature.js 3.18 KiB {0} [built]
[193] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/eddsa/index.js 3.43 KiB {0} [built]
[194] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/eddsa/key.js 2.44 KiB {0} [built]
[195] ./node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/eddsa/signature.js 1.66 KiB {0} [built]
[196] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[197] ./node_modules/parse-asn1/asn1.js 3.14 KiB {0} [built]
[198] ./node_modules/asn1.js/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
[199] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[200] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/api.js 1.48 KiB {0} [built]
[201] ./node_modules/vm-browserify/index.js 3.98 KiB {0} [optional] [built]
[202] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/reporter.js 2.58 KiB {0} [built]
[203] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/base/node.js 16.2 KiB {0} [built]
[204] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/constants/der.js 792 bytes {0} [built]
[205] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/decoders/index.js 91 bytes {0} [built]
[206] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/decoders/pem.js 1.15 KiB {0} [built]
[207] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/encoders/index.js 91 bytes {0} [built]
[208] ./node_modules/asn1.js/lib/asn1/encoders/pem.js 590 bytes {0} [built]
[209] ./node_modules/parse-asn1/certificate.js 2.37 KiB {0} [built]
[210] ./node_modules/parse-asn1/aesid.json 501 bytes {0} [built]
[211] ./node_modules/parse-asn1/fixProc.js 1.21 KiB {0} [built]
[212] ./node_modules/browserify-sign/browser/verify.js 2.37 KiB {0} [built]
[213] ./node_modules/create-ecdh/browser.js 2.63 KiB {0} [built]
[214] ./node_modules/create-ecdh/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js 85.3 KiB {0} [built]
[215] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[216] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/browser.js 327 bytes {0} [built]
[217] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/publicEncrypt.js 2.27 KiB {0} [built]
[218] buffer (ignored) 15 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
[219] ./node_modules/public-encrypt/privateDecrypt.js 2.37 KiB {0} [built]
[220] ./node_modules/randomfill/browser.js 2.93 KiB {0} [built]
[221] ./node_modules/crypto-js/lib-typedarrays.js 2.18 KiB {0} [built]
[222] ./node_modules/crypto-js/enc-utf16.js 3.99 KiB {0} [built]
[223] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha224.js 1.87 KiB {0} [built]
[224] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha384.js 2.21 KiB {0} [built]
[225] ./node_modules/crypto-js/sha3.js 10.4 KiB {0} [built]
[226] ./node_modules/crypto-js/ripemd160.js 9.17 KiB {0} [built]
[227] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pbkdf2.js 4.43 KiB {0} [built]
[228] ./node_modules/crypto-js/mode-cfb.js 2.07 KiB {0} [built]
[229] ./node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ctr.js 1.43 KiB {0} [built]
[230] ./node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ctr-gladman.js 2.28 KiB {0} [built]
[231] ./node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ofb.js 1.3 KiB {0} [built]
[232] ./node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ecb.js 893 bytes {0} [built]
[233] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pad-ansix923.js 1.24 KiB {0} [built]
[234] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pad-iso10126.js 1.09 KiB {0} [built]
[235] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pad-iso97971.js 918 bytes {0} [built]
[236] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pad-zeropadding.js 1.08 KiB {0} [built]
[237] ./node_modules/crypto-js/pad-nopadding.js 554 bytes {0} [built]
[238] ./node_modules/crypto-js/format-hex.js 1.78 KiB {0} [built]
[239] ./node_modules/crypto-js/aes.js 8.45 KiB {0} [built]
[240] ./node_modules/crypto-js/tripledes.js 24.3 KiB {0} [built]
[241] ./node_modules/crypto-js/rc4.js 3.49 KiB {0} [built]
[242] ./node_modules/crypto-js/rabbit.js 6.52 KiB {0} [built]
[243] ./node_modules/crypto-js/rabbit-legacy.js 6.56 KiB {0} [built]

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  bundle.js (706 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (706 KiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Comment: ````"target": "es5",```` polyfillsы там всякие разные будут.

Comment: @lijil к сожалению дело не в этом. Изменение target, в данном случае, не влияет на результат. И судя по коду crypto-js, написана она с поддержкой es5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина оказалась в том, что у webpack'a в зависимостях есть пакет [node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v4.43.0/package.json#L25), который в свою очередь содержит зависимость от пакета [crypto-browserify](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser/blob/master/package.json#L16), который и привносит данные polyfill'ы при попытке использовать модуль [crypto](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/core.js#L28), от чего размер файла раздувается в разы.

Для меня решением стало установка параметра `node` в **webpack.config.js** в `false`. Детальней: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

Итоговый вид **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    node: false,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/build'),
    },
    plugins: [],
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    warnings: false,
                    parse: {},
                    compress: {},
                    mangle: true,
                    output: null,
                    toplevel: false,
                    nameCache: null,
                    ie8: false,
                    keep_fnames: false,
                },
            }),
        ]
    },
};
```

Вес бандла при этом: **49.7 кб**

Upd: в 5й версии webpack опция `node` будет больше недоступной https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#test-webpack-5-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

А исследование содержимого бандла дало какие-то результаты?
Возможно посмотрев по исходникам не удаляя комментариев будет возможность узнать какой код содержит большой объем.

Кроме того, в новой версии webpack есть возможность дробить код и например весь код импортируемый из node_modules вынести в отдельный файл vendor.js, а файл с вашими исходниками main.js.
Для этого рекомендую почитать про optimization опцию файла конфигурации webpack.

Comment: Исследование содержимого бандла показало, что в нем помимо необходимого crypto-js содержится 229 модулей которые не были никак запрошены/задействованы.